# npm install of sparkLines causing error

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-install, sparklines

I was trying to install sparklines for a tutorial i'm doing from online. When I try to install it using npm I get the below error.
Anyone know how to solve this. I tried updating my react to 15.3.0 but that causes a bunch of errors to happen.

```
npm WARN EPEERINVALID react-addons-shallow-compare@15.3.0 requires a peer of react@^15.3.0 but none was installed.
```

Here is my package Json

```
{
  "name": "redux-simple-starter",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Simple starter package for Redux with React and Babel support",
  "main": "index.js",
  "repository": "git@github.com:StephenGrider/ReduxSimpleStarter.git",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js",
    "test": "mocha --compilers js:babel-core/register --require ./test/test_helper.js --recursive ./test",
    "test:watch": "npm run test -- --watch"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.2.1",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.1.18",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.1.18",
    "chai": "^3.5.0",
    "chai-jquery": "^2.0.0",
    "jquery": "^2.2.1",
    "jsdom": "^8.1.0",
    "mocha": "^2.4.5",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "^0.14.7",
    "webpack": "^1.12.9",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.13.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-1": "^6.1.18",
    "lodash": "^3.10.1",
    "react": "^0.14.3",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.3",
    "react-redux": "^4.0.0",
    "react-router": "^2.0.1",
    "react-sparklines": "^1.6.0",
    "redux": "^3.0.4",
    "redux-promise": "^0.5.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: It's a `warn`. Have you tried just ignoring it?

Comment: Yea I tried to ignore it but it wont install react-sparklines.